# ¿Error al registrar a la base de datos android studio?

Tags: c#, android-studio, asp.net-web-api, retrofit

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Estoy realizando un registro a la base de datos usando `android` con `retrofit` y `asp.net` web api. El problema es que en el webapi obtiene el valor `firmaDigital` nulo, pero desde android studio si le envía el dato.

Clase Firma

```
public class Firma
    {
        public int idFirma { get; set; }
        public byte[] firmaDigital { get; set; }
    }
```

interfaz del metodo registrar

```
@POST("Firma")
    Call<Firma> createFirma(@Body Firma obj);
```

Método registrar

```
private void registrarFirma() {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();

        IFirmaService service = retrofit.create(IFirmaService.class);

        Firma firma = new Firma();
        firma.setFirmaDigital(mSig.getBytes());

        Call<Firma> call = service.createFirma(firma);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Firma>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Firma> call, Response<Firma> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Se registro correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Firma> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e( "Error: ",t.getMessage() );
            }
        });

    }
```

Método registrar en webapi

```
private CrudMvcApiEntities db = new CrudMvcApiEntities();

        [ResponseType(typeof(Firma))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostFirma(Firma obj)//obj.firmaDigital=null
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Firmas.Add(obj);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = obj.idFirma }, obj);
        }
```

Comment: Descartando algo básico, las clases Firma de la API y de Android tienen el mismo nombre de la propiedad `firmaDigital`?

Comment: en ninguna parte veo que uses la propiedad firmaDigital, usas una llamada setFirmaDigital, seguro que se llaman igual?

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que le hace falta indicar como va a recibir el payload el web api. Intente con el siguiente código:

```
private CrudMvcApiEntities db = new CrudMvcApiEntities();

        [ResponseType(typeof(Firma))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostFirma([FromBody]Firma obj)//obj.firmaDigital=null
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Firmas.Add(obj);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = obj.idFirma }, obj);
        }
```

Estoy suponiendo que es un [FromBody] pero si no debe indicarle cual es [FromUri] o el que sea .

Comment: no funciona me llega el valor firmaDigital null en el webapi, porque desde android si lo tiene

Comment: Podría mostrar el json que esta generando con android?

Comment: devuelve BAD_REQUEST

Comment: Ok si por lo mismo te digo que si puedes mostrar el json que se esta generando en el android

Comment: {"Valor demasiado grande o demasiado pequeño para un byte sin firmar."}

Comment: Pueden ser varias cosas. Pero pareciera que usted tiene en su tabla de base de datos un tipo int  y el valor que ocupa es un bigint (Int64)  o al revés que en su tabla tenga un Int64 y esta recibiendo un Int32. Yo empezaría por revisar eso y segundo podría ser que el array de bites excede la capacidad definida en la bd , osea el tamaño de el campo para el arreglo de bites es muy pequeño y se esta quedando corto. Otra cosa que tiene que validar bien es que el json que recibe sea compatible con el que quiere procesar en el web api

Comment: Mi tabla Firma tiene un idFirma int, firmaDigital image en sql server

Comment: Al hacer debug en android envío la clase Firma  con datos, el problema es cuando se conecta al webapi el valor del objeto Firma: el atributo firmaDigital tiene el valor null, pero desde android si le envío el dato.

Comment: si eso es porque el tipo dato que usted esta enviando desde android en el atributo firmaDigital no es el mismo que lee el webapi o no lo esta reconociendo. Asegúrese que el byte array del android sea equivalente al byte de array que recibe en web api

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115544/discussion-between-dum-and-richard-viquez-perez).